# using GPS sensor on ultrabook

Tags: wpf, geolocation

I am developing a WPF application on an Intel Ultrabook.  As the Ultrabook already includes GPS sensors, how can I go about retrieving my current location inside my app using this sensor?

I am not able to find any sample code to get me started.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher(v=vs.100).aspx

especially the statement:

> To begin accessing location data, create a GeoCoordinateWatcher and call Start or TryStart to initiate the acquisition of data from the current location provider.
>
> The Status property can be checked to determine if data is available. If data is available, you can get the location one time from the Position property, or receive continuous location updates by handling the PositionChanged event.